# Remove Comma "," from this JS output and use Line Break instead of , Comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a text box and `Go!` button, when i insert multiline to this text box and press Go button then this change value as `<img src="one line">,<img src="second line">,<img src="third line">,...`  and so on.

But here i want to remove `,` Comma and use Line Break means simply my result should be as :

```
<img src="one line">
<img src="second line">
<img src="third line">
```

My Whole Code is here:

```js
$('#go').click(function() {
  var lines = $('#input').val().split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
  var output = [];
  var outputText = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // only push this line if it contains a non whitespace character.
    if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
      outputText.push('<img src="' + $.trim(lines[0]) + '">');
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
  $('#input').val('' + outputText + '');
 })
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25px;
}
#input {
  height: 150px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" class="u-full-width" placeholder=""></textarea>
<input id="go" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Go!">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried `.(split)` in many ways for that but I wasn't able to solve that.

Comment: `outputText` is not text, but an array. You just need to use `outputText.join('\n')`.

Comment: can you explain me plz where i should use outputText.join('\n')

Comment: In the `$('#input').val('' + outputText + '');` line. What you're currently doing there coerces the array to a string, leading to the commas.

Comment: Yah ! its working now

Answer (score 0):

```
yourtext.split(",").join("\n")
```

splits `yourtext` with comma as a separator and joins the resulting array into a string, separating the elements with newline. You can also use `replaceAll`:

```
const regex = /,/gi;

console.log(yourtext.replaceAll(regex, 'ferret'));
```